# What kind of snake is this? Seen on Koh Lanta, Thailand

Tags: species-identification, snake

We had this snake in our bungalow on Koh Lanta, Thailand. From the reaction of the employees at the resort I can tell that it is venomous, but that's all I know. I am curious, does anybody know what species it is?

Thanks and cheers, Philip!

[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide an image showing the snakes head? That would make identification much easier. Currently I'm thinking it's a chinese rat snake (quite common in Thailand), even though you said the employees are acting like it's venomous. [see here for image](https://www.google.com/search?rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-US%3AIE-Address&biw=1920&bih=1086&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=Indo-Chinese+rat+snake+dark&oq=Indo-Chinese+rat+snake+dark&gs_l=psy-ab.3...194038.194490.0.194601.5.5.0.0.0.0.152.430.0j3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.1.150...0i13i30k1.C6PHE7qAyjg#imgrc=Ooeh5aH_PoYFGM:&spf=1502910525870)

Answer (score 1):

If the resort is near a water body then it is highly likely that it is a keelback snake.
For determining whether it is poisonous or not it is extremely important to look at the scale pattern on its ventral side(belly). Unfortunately that is not visible here.